# Touch, swipe or drag events emulating on Android not working

Tags: android, adb, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

After reading posts I figured out how to emulate a touch event :

> adb shell input tap 100 100

I've installed MagicMarker in order to see if anything is drawn, nothing appears.

I've also tried with monkeyrunner/androidViewClient Touch functions :

> device.touch(100 , 100, 'DOWN_AND_UP');

My whole code for AndroidViewClient :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import getopt, sys
import os

# Add android to path becayuse it seems to not appear on windows

sys.path.append("D:/Dev/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools")
sys.path.append("D:/Dev/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/lib")
sys.path.append("D:/Dev/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools")

# PyDev sets PYTHONPATH, use it
try:
    for p in os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(':'):
        if not p in sys.path:
            sys.path.append(p)
except:
    pass

try:
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
    pass

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, ViewNotFoundException
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()   
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)
device.touch(100,100,"DOWN_AND_UP")
```

I successfully used device.press("KEYCODE_MENU", "DOWN_AND_UP") or device.takeSnapshot(), I don't understand at all why touch events are not received by my handset.

By the way, I am using real devices (a GS3 and GS4 both in 4.3)

Do not hesitate to ask further information.

Comment: I have not yet succeeds in using the monkeyrunner Drag function but :
- MagicMarker is not a good way to test touch events
- adb shell input swipe x0 y0 x1 y1 works like a charm

I still would like to know why the drag function is not working, will pursue my anlysis :)

Comment: Looking at Monkeyrunner's source code, they do not have a **swipe** event for a device: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/6db5720/monkeyrunner/src/com/android/monkeyrunner/MonkeyDevice.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested **MagicMarker** using this simple *[AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)* script.
Notice that some fixes to `adbclient.drag()` were introduced in version 5.1.1 so be sure you have the latest version.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2014  Diego Torres Milano
'''

__requires__ = ["androidviewclient >= 5.1.1"]
import pkg_resources
from com.dtmilano.android.adb.adbclient import AdbClient

AdbClient(serialno='.*').drag((100, 100), (400, 400), 1000)
```

This produces:

[image]

Also notice than in your script `device` is the `AdbClient` instance.

If you check how `drag()` is implemented in `AdbClient`, you'll see that is using `input swipe` with parameters according to the corresponding API level:

```
def drag(self, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), duration, steps=1):
'''
Sends drag event (actually it's using C{input swipe} command.

@param (x0, y0): starting point
@param (x1, y1): ending point
@param duration: duration of the event in ms
@param steps: number of steps (currently ignored by @{input swipe}
'''

version = int(self.getProperty('ro.build.version.sdk'))
if version <= 15:
    raise RuntimeError('drag: API <= 15 not supported (version=%d)' % version)
elif version <= 17:
    self.shell('input swipe %d %d %d %d' % (x0, y0, x1, y1))
else:
    self.shell('input swipe %d %d %d %d %d' % (x0, y0, x1, y1, duration))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Indeed I had an older version of AVC (4.6.0), I made the update but it is still not working. In fact, it seems whenever a drag function got a duration, it is not working. The only drag motions I could made were : device.shell('input swipe 300 1270 300 10') but it was too slow and inacurate. For now, I'm using the "ugly" method of touchDown<->several touchMoves <-> touchUp, which is working well

Comment: See my edit, it may give you some hints about how drag is translated to swipe

Comment: @dtmilano Where are all of the new sample scripts for the 5.1.1? Can't seem to find them and the stuff [here](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/tree/master/AndroidViewClient/examples) all looks a few years old...

Comment: These are the latest examples. Perhaps a bit old but they should work with latest versions too.